# R - Remove all row that only have NA

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have this type of dataset with ID, age and gender and then questions the ID's have responded in a survey:

```
> ID gender age Q1 Q2 Q3
  1  male   35  1  1   NA
  2  male   45  NA NA  NA
  3 female  55  NA NA  NA
```

I want to remove all rows where all Q´s is NA, so in this case the result will be:

```
> ID gender age Q1 Q2 Q3
  1  male   35  1  1   NA
```

How can I do so with `data.table`?

Comment: Try `df[!rowSums(is.na(df[-c(1:3)])) == ncol(df[-c(1:3)]),]`

Comment: what if i have a dataset with 5000 rows, how can I upgrade this line of code :)

Comment: It doesn't matter how many rows you have. Code remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(if_any(starts_with("Q"), ~ !is.na(.x)))

# A tibble: 1 × 6
     ID gender   age    Q1    Q2 Q3   
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     1 male      35     1     1 NA
```

Comment: Same as `df %>% 
  filter(!if_all(starts_with("Q"), ~ is.na(.)))`.

Answer (score 1):

One data.table option:

```
DT[ DT[, apply(.SD, 1, \(x) any(!is.na(x))), .SDcols = q1:q3] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
dt[rowSums(is.na(dt[, paste0("Q", 1:3)])) != length(paste0("Q", 1:3)), ]
```

Or to make it agnostic over the names:

```r
cols <- startsWith(colnames(dt), "Q")
dt[rowSums(is.na(dt[, ..cols])) != sum(cols), ]
```